# How to return result after bulkCopy.WriteToServer

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlbulkcopy

**UPDATE** based on accepted answer:

```
bool success = false;
using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection)) //using!
{
    connection.Open();

    //explicit isolation level is best-practice
    using (var tran = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
    {
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "table";
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings...

        using (var dataReader = new ObjectDataReader<SomeObject>(paths))
        {            
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataReader);
            success = true;
        }

        tran.Commit(); //commit, will not be called if exception escapes
    }
}
return success;
```

I use `BulkCopy` class for large insert and it works fine.
After execute `WriteToServer` and saving data to database 
I wan't to know are all data saved successfully so I can return `true/false` because I need to save all or nothing?

```
    var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection);

    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "table";

    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings...

    using (var dataReader = new ObjectDataReader<SomeObject>(paths))
    {
        try
        {
        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataReader);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){ ... }    
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the call to `WriteToServer` completed without exceptions, all rows were saved and are on disk. This is just the standard semantics for SQL Server DML. Nothing special with bulk copy.

Like all other DML, `SqlBulkCopy` is all-or-nothing as well. Except if you configure a batch size which you did not.

```
using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection)) //using!
{
    connection.Open();

    //explicit isolation level is best-practice
    using (var tran = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
    {
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "table";
        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings...

        using (var dataReader = new ObjectDataReader<SomeObject>(paths))
        {
            //try
            //{
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataReader, /*here you set some options*/);
            //}
            //catch(Exception ex){ ... } //you need no explicit try-catch here
        }

        tran.Commit(); //commit, will not be called if exception escapes
    }
}
```

I've added you sample code that I aligned with best-practices.

Comment: Ok, if I understand right if I try to store 1.000.000 rows and code fall to catch at row 8.000.000 nothing will be saved in db. Am I right (I have updated a code in questione little)?

Comment: Exactly. To make this more clear I recommend that you use an explicit transaction (`connection.BeginTransaction()`) and commit it only when no exception happened. That makes it totally clear what is happening.

Comment: Thanks. If I don't ask too much can you provide one sample code to be sure that I do everything right?

Comment: I've added you sample code that I aligned with best-practices. Feel free to modify it to your needs. You don't need to follow it exactly.

Comment: Last line should be tran.Commit(); instead tran.Complete(); right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38419/discussion-between-1110-and-usr)

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way of identifying if the process was completed successfully or not, other than to look for/catch any exceptions raised by `WriteToServer()` method.

An alternative approach might be to check the number of records in the database, and then check the number of records after the process completes - The difference being the number that were inserted.  Comparing this value against the numbers of records to be inserted could give an idea of failure or success.  However, this is not fool proof particularly if there are other process inserting/deleting records.

However, these techniques in conjunction with `TransactionScope` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx - or something similar should achieve what you require.

**EDIT**

By Default each insert operation is processed as a batch; if the operation fails in a particular batch then that batch is rolled back, not any inserted before it.

However, If an internal transaction is applied to the bulk operation than a failure in **any** row can roll back the entire result set.  For Example;

```
using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy =
   new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity
                   | SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction))
{
   bulkCopy.BatchSize = 10;
   bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.BulkCopyDemoMatchingColumns";

   try
   {
      bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
   }
   finally
   {
      bulkCopy.Close();
   }
}
```

An error in any of the above operation would cause the entire operation to roll back.  See more details on this at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tchktcdk.aspx.

Comment: When I execute WriteToServer is that all or nothing save? I mean if code crash and goes to catch nothing wil be saved right?

Comment: @1110 WriteToServer by default will only roll back the row that caused the error; not any that are saved before.  If you need that functionality, then you need to use transactions. I have expanded answer to include a sample transaction.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/434atets.aspx) for this function, the following snippet suggests that you should catch any exceptions that are thrown and otherwise you can take it that the operation was successful.

```
using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString))
{
     bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.BulkCopyDemoMatchingColumns";
     try
     {
         // Write from the source to the destination.
         bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
     }
     finally
     {
         // Close the SqlDataReader. The SqlBulkCopy 
         // object is automatically closed at the end 
         // of the using block.
         reader.Close();
     }
}
```

If you want to be super-sure, execute a query against the database to check the rows are there, after the bulk copy completes.